# Can't find kernel for vscode jupyter

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to install wolfram kernel for jupyter notebook (vscode) because vscode extension: wolfram language notebook doesn't work.But when I finished installation something werid happended.
I can find wolfram kernel in command line : jupyter kernelspec list, but not in my vscode [image]

Hope someone can tell me how vscode jupyter works?

Answer (score 0):

So I hope my solution (on Linux) will work for you too:

1. get the repository:
   https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter
2. add the kernel by executing: wolframscript configure-jupyter.wls add
3. check if the kernel is added: jupyter kernelspec list
4. in vscode search for "select Interpreter to start jupyter server" and select your python version

Now the kernels should be updated and you should be able to choose your installed wolfram kernel.

In case its not working I installed the package

> python"version"-wolframalpha

. However I do not know if that is necessary.